# Search for List&Label Drilldown documentation or samples

Tags: c#, report, drilldown, listlabel

We're searching for a documentation to integrate List&Label Drilldowns into our reports.

The official documentation is really bad in my eyes. We've got some code snippets from their support but only with untyped data and without any comments.

```
object[] restrictions = new Object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" };
DataTable table = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, restrictions);

OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + tableName + "] WHERE OrderID > 11040", onn));

object[] restrictions1 = new Object[] { null, null, null, null };
DataTable table1 = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Foreign_Keys, restrictions1);

ds.Relations.Add(new DataRelation(relationName, ds.Tables[parentTable].Columns[parentCol], ds.Tables[childTable].Columns[childCol]));
```

We do not know why they use an array of null objects here and how to generate reports with `IEnumerable<MyClass>` as requested. At the end this didnt help and we're still on search how to pass typed data a report with drilldown data.

Maybe anybody can help here and provide some best practise experiences?

Answer (score 1):

The snippets you've pasted are not LL specific but rather a generic way to parse tables and relations via ADO.NET. Assuming you have an `IEnumerable<Customer>` 
where the Customer class is defined along the lines of

```
class Customer
{
    //Constructor
    public Customer(int customerID, string companyName, string contactName, string address, string city)
    {
        CustomerID = customerID;
        CompanyName = companyName;
        ContactName = contactName;
        Address = address;
        City = city;
        OrderList = new List<Order>();
    }

    public List<Order> OrderList { get; set; }

    // The CustomerID should not be available in the designer
    [Browsable(false)]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    // Set display name, which should be used in the designer
    [DisplayName("Name")]
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}

// The "Order" class represents a single order of a customer
class Order
{
    //Constructor
    public Order(int orderID, DateTime orderDate, string shipName, string shipCountry, double price)
    {
        OrderID = orderID;
        OrderDate = orderDate;
        ShipName = shipName;
        ShipCountry = shipCountry;
        Price = price;
    }

    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public string ShipName { get; set; }
    public string ShipCountry { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    // Explicitly set a barcode field type
    [FieldType(LlFieldType.Barcode_EAN128)]
    public string PriceEan
    {
        get { return Price.ToString(); }
    }
}
```

all you usually have to do is

```
using (ListLabel LL = new ListLabel())
{
    LL.DataSource = MyCustomerList;
    LL.Design();
}
```

This will give you all the features there are, including drilldown etc. from the `Customer`to the `Order` class. I've also added examples for the available attributes to fine tune the results.

Comment: Did my snippet help then? If not, can you try to be more specific in your question? If you need sample code, try the ObjectDataProvider sample, it shows how to bind to numerous object data sources, including `IEnumerable<Class>`

Comment: the problem in our case are the basics. We do not know how we have to design our typed structure for drilldowns. We have an idea now how to use drilldowns with DataSets, but we do not have our data in DataSets, we have full filled objects in collections. We know we have to use `LL.DataSource` but.. not how the DataSource should look alike. We do not find any simple sample to understand how the data structure have to be.

Comment: @Ben I've extended the sample above by some parts of the sample I quoted. Basically, the data structure doesn't have to follow a fixed scheme, LL uses reflection to parse your structure as it is.